# How to form a list with the elements given by Racklog recursively?

Tags: racket

I am starting to read about Racklog, which is somewhat the logic programming extension to Racket, and so far I know that I can great predicates and goals in the following way:

```
(define %coffee
  (%rel ()
        [('moka)]
        [('turkish)]
        [('expresso)]
        [('cappuccino)]
        [('latte)]))
```

and when I use the instruction %which and %more starts to show if the goals are fulfilled or not, like the following:

```
(%which (c) (%coffee c))
((c . moka))

(%more)
((c . turkish))
```

Until it reaches #f when there are no more predicates to evaluate. So I was wondering if I could extract the results from these predicates evaluation and to form a list recursively. I have programmed the following:

```
(define (test data)
  (if (eq? data #f)
      '()
      (cons (%which (c) (%coffee c))(test (%more)))))
(test %coffee)
```

However, it enters an infinite loop: how I can form a list with the results of %more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`%more`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/racklog/glossary.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racklog%2Fmain..rkt%29._%7E25more%29%29) retries the goal in the last %which-query for a different solution, so you have to call `(%which (c) (%coffee c))` only once and then call repeatedly `(%more)` to get other results:

```
#lang racket
(require racklog)

(define %coffee
  (%rel ()
        [('moka)]
        [('turkish)]
        [('expresso)]
        [('cappuccino)]
        [('latte)]))

(define (test data)
  (if data
      (cons data (test (%more)))
      '()))

(test (%which (c) (%coffee c)))
```

Result:

```
'(((c . moka)) ((c . turkish)) ((c . expresso)) ((c . cappuccino)) ((c . latte)))
```